# Carbon laravel получить день

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

есть дата `$request->datestart = '2018-10-02'`

я пытаюсь получить день `return Carbon::parse($request->datestart)->format('d');`

но выводит 02, чтобы без нуля это переводить в строку и удалять?

Comment: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters : return a Carbon::parse($request->datestart)->day;

Comment: подскажите а можно в дате $request->datestart = '2018-10-02' заменить только день? на другой?

Comment: Прочитайте документацию и ответьте на этот вопрос нам, тут.

Comment: не нашел как сделать замену только дня

Comment: $request->datestart = Carbon::parse($request->datestart)->day(13)->format('Y-m-d');

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй:

```
return (int) Carbon::parse($request->datestart)->format('d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
return Carbon::parse($request->datestart)->day;
```